# How to iterate over a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making a get request to receive data. The requests and response is below. I am trying to iterate over the results and do 2 things:

1. Iterate over an undefined number of pages (max 100 results per page so I need to paginate over my response to get all results).
2. Print/Return the list of orders where CombinedPaymentStatus = PAID.

I'm sure my request isn't complete however I'm stuck at this point. I have gotten this error most recently:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 129 (char 128)`.

I thought using the variable `paymentStatus` would help, the index `[1]` is static so will not iterate over each item in the array.

Request:

```
import requests
import json
import config

url = 'https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/saleList?Page=25&Limit=100&CreatedSince=2021-05-01'

payload = {}
headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "api-auth-accountid": config.liveAccountid,
  "api-auth-applicationkey": config.liveApplicationKey
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

paymentStatus = response.json()["SaleList"][1]["CombinedPaymentStatus"]
total = response.json()["Total"]
page = response.json()["Page"]

for paymentStatus in response:
    json.loads(paymentStatus)
    print(paymentStatus)
```

Response:

```
{
 "Total": 6471,
 "Page": 1,
 "SaleList": [
 {
  "SaleID": "6222cb47-0e1e-450d-af6d-0cefcee9eef7",
  "OrderNumber": "SO-00092",
  "Status": "ORDERED",
  "OrderDate": "2017-09-29T00:00:00Z",
  "InvoiceDate": null,
  "Customer": "Rock Star Transport",
  "CustomerID": "74de0528-fae7-4233-9222-e92110d57f5a",
  "InvoiceNumber": null,
  "CustomerReference": "",
  "InvoiceAmount": 0,
  "PaidAmount": 0,
  "InvoiceDueDate": null,
  "ShipBy": null,
  "BaseCurrency": "RUB",
  "CustomerCurrency": "RUB",
  "CreditNoteNumber": null,
  "Updated": "2017-09-29T03:03:13.913Z",
  "QuoteStatus": "AUTHORISED",
  "OrderStatus": "AUTHORISED",
  "CombinedPickingStatus": "PICKED",
  "CombinedPaymentStatus": "PAID",
  "CombinedTrackingNumbers": "",
  "CombinedPackingStatus": "PACKED",
  "CombinedShippingStatus": "SHIPPING",
  "CombinedInvoiceStatus": "INVOICED",
  "CreditNoteStatus": "NOT AVAILABLE",
  "FulFilmentStatus": "NOT FULFILLED",
  "Type": "Advanced Sale",
  "SourceChannel": "Amazon_US",
  "ExternalID": null,
  "OrderLocationID": "8b5d4343-c007-43d7-8e8f-6fa6c0d29f22"
 },
 {
  "SaleID": "a6558396-8893-479b-bca9-f89ea3e54633",
  "OrderNumber": "SO-00091",
  "Status": "BACKORDERED",
  "OrderDate": "2017-09-28T00:00:00Z",
  "InvoiceDate": "2017-09-28T00:00:00Z",
  "Customer": "Rock Star Transport",
  "CustomerID": "9a4513e9-a7a4-4ee5-b240-84cfd8944cde",
  "InvoiceNumber": "INV-06073",
  "CustomerReference": "19614",
  "InvoiceAmount": 0,
  "PaidAmount": 0,
  "InvoiceDueDate": "2017-10-02T00:00:00Z",
  "ShipBy": "2017-09-29T00:00:00Z",
  "BaseCurrency": "RUB",
  "CustomerCurrency": "AUD",
  "CreditNoteNumber": null,
  "Updated": "2017-09-29T03:00:48.043Z",
  "QuoteStatus": "NOT AVAILABLE",
  "OrderStatus": "AUTHORISED",
  "CombinedPickingStatus": "NOT PICKED",
  "CombinedPaymentStatus": "UNPAID",
  "CombinedTrackingNumbers": "",
  "CombinedPackingStatus": "NOT PACKED",
  "CombinedShippingStatus": "NOT SHIPPED",
  "CombinedInvoiceStatus": "NOT INVOICED",
  "CreditNoteStatus": "NOT AVAILABLE",
  "FulFilmentStatus": "NOT FULFILLED",
  "Type": "Simple Sale",
  "SourceChannel": null,
  "ExternalID": null,
  "OrderLocationID": "8b5d4343-c007-43d7-8e8f-6fa6c0d29f22"
 }
 ]
}
```

Comment: BTW API docs are here if you're interested: https://dearinventory.docs.apiary.io/#reference/sale/sale-list

Comment: If your question really is 'How to iterate over a 2D array in Python'  that's a LOT of text to ask it.. could you please consider editing your question title, or the body of your question (see Help > How to Ask)?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Run `for paymentStatus in response: print(paymentStatus)` to see what you're actually doing. And then try `for x in response: print(x)` to get a clue.

Comment: Yes that's what I need help with. Don't know what you mean @JeffUK

Comment: I get that error I provided regarding bytes @Timus. It's not working